# "Handbook on" or "Handbook of"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, prepositions, collocation

Which of the following is grammatically correct as a title for a book?

1. 'Handbook on Right to Information Act'
2. 'Handbook of Right to Information Act'

Apparently both the usages are employed. See [book1](http://www.amazon.in/Handbook-Right-Information-2013-Reprint/dp/9350352605?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=0d3c4a39-525f-487d-a560-09b9d4c95ab8) and [book2](http://www.amazon.in/Handbook-of-Right-to-Information/dp/8184552467/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1495740208&sr=1-5&keywords=handbook+of+right+to+information).

Would the answer change if the words 'Right to Information Act' were replaced by 'Microbiology' or if the word 'Handbook' was replaced by 'Book'?

Comment: http://www.crchandbook.com/. Also note that your *book1* uses ***the*** and *book2* does not include ***Act***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ngram suggests that “Handbook of” is more popular.

[image: ngram]

Personally, I do not like the sound of either, as it seems redundant to include handbook in the title of a handbook! I do prefer having a definite article in there. “Handbook on the Right to Information Act” or “Handbook of the Right to Information Act”.

In this instance, I would suggest the meaning is slightly different, which could also account for the popularity difference in ngram. The first (on) is referring to a specific noun that the handbook will cover. The second (of) is referring to a topic that the handbook will be about. In practice, these are not far apart in many cases, so either will work.

In this case, I think “on” works better because (I assume) the handbook is about a particular act (the Right to Information Act).

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using 'to' - "The handbook to the Right to Information Act", "The handbook to better living".